# Assigning specific value in function of variable last element

Tags: python

Is there anyway I could do this in a more clean and optimized way?

```
def get_player_move(move):
    letter=""
    ciff =""
    if move[0]=="1":
        letter ="A"

    elif move[0]=="2":
        letter = "B"

    elif move[0]=="3":
        letter ="C"

    elif move[0]== "4":
        letter ="D"



    if move[1]=="1":
        ciff ="4" 

    elif move[1]=="2":
        ciff ="3"

    elif move[1]== "3":
        ciff="2"
    elif move[1]== "4":

        ciff="1"

    player_move = letter+ciff
    return player_move
```

Move get his value from here `get_player_move(source.objectName()[-1] + source.objectName()[12])` So i have to change 4321 into 1234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare one *list* with your `letters` and one with your `numbers`.

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

and just use `indexing`.

```
player_move = letters[int(move[0]) - 1] + numbers[len(numbers) - int(move[1])]
```

Another approach and one shorter *solution* could be using `chr` *function*. For instance, `chr(97)` return `a`, so in our version `A` could be obtained as

```
chr(96 + int(move[0])).upper()
```

So, using what I described above we have *one-line* `solution`:

```
def get_player_move(move):
     return chr(96 + int(move[0])).upper() + str(4 - int(move[1]) + 1)
print(get_player_move(["1", "2"]))
```

Output

```
A3
```